# WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-netaccessor-libcurl

Tags: c++, apache, libcurl, xerces, shibboleth

I am trying to install Xerces-C to my Shibboleth 2 SP following this guide:
https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPLinuxSourceBuild

But when i run: `./configure --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp --disable-netaccessor-libcurl`
i get this warning:  `WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-netaccessor-libcurl`

```
[...]
config.status: creating src/xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp
config.status: src/xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing libtool-rpath-patch commands
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-netaccessor-libcurl
configure:
configure: Report:
configure:   File Manager: POSIX
configure:   Mutex Manager: POSIX
configure:   Transcoder: icu
configure:   NetAccessor: curl
configure:   Message Loader: inmemory
```

I tried to passing it and `make` and `make install` but does not install it and i get something like:

```
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/opt/xerces-c-3.1.1/samples'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/opt/xerces-c-3.1.1/samples'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/opt/xerces-c-3.1.1'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/opt/xerces-c-3.1.1'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/home/user/opt/shibboleth-sp/lib/pkgconfig" || /bin/mkdir -p "/home/user/opt/shibboleth-sp/lib/pkgconfig"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 xerces-c.pc '/home/user/opt/shibboleth-sp/lib/pkgconfig'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/opt/xerces-c-3.1.1'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/opt/xerces-c-3.1.1'
```

What does that mean?
Thank you!

Comment: It means it doesn't recognize that option.  Did you try not passing it? Maybe the instructions are out of date with respect to the package you downloaded.  This page: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Xerces-C indicates you might want `--enable-netaccessor-socket` instead.  Is there a reason you don't want OpenSSL included?

Comment: Thank you! I tried to passing it and `make` and `make install` but does not install it.

Comment: @CarlNorum I have tried with `./configure --enable-netaccessor-socket --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp` but doesn't work. So I have to install **OpenSSL** to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have the same question; so I'm asking on Shib Users ‎[users@shibboleth.net]‎

Comment: `--enable-netaccessor-socket` worked for me.  Also, the warning did not prevent my build from working