# XML-Security-C: configure: error: unable to find xerces header files

Tags: c++, xerces-c, shibboleth

I am trying to install Shibboleth 2 SP following this guide:
[*Building the Native Shibboleth 2 SP from Source on Linux*](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPLinuxSourceBuild)

I configure and built **log4shib** successfully, and then I tried to build **Xerces-C++ 3.1.1** but it gave me a warning: [`WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-netaccessor-libcurl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778371/warning-unrecognized-options-disable-netaccessor-libcurl) and i solved this issue without using that option because is not available in 3.1, "`--disable-netaccessor-libcurl`" is not listed on:
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html

Then I built it whitout get any error o warning.
The third step is to install XML-Security-C but when i run:

```
./configure --without-xalan --disable-static --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp
```

i get this error:

```
configure: error: unable to find xerces header files
```

I treid to export the path:

```
export PATH=$HOME/opt/shibboleth-sp/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/opt/shibboleth-sp/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export XERCESCROOT=$HOME/opt/shibboleth-sp:$XERCESCROOT
```

and as suggested by @Brian:

```
export CPPFLAGS=$HOME/opt/shibboleth-sp/include
export CFLAGS=$HOME/opt/shibboleth-sp/include
```

and trying to install again, but doesn't work.

In the folder `/opt/shibboleth-sp` i have this folders (in /shibboleth-sp i don't have a folder called *xercesc* but this is inside /include):

```
/bin/
    DOMCount (file)
    SAX2Count (file)
    SAX2Print (file)
    etc..
/include/
    log4shib
    xercesc
        dom
        framework
        internal
        parsers
        sax
        etc..
/lib/
    liblog4shib.so
    libxerces-c.so
    etc..
/share/
    aclocal
```

[image]


I hope someone can help me.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your setting, give ./configure the flag --with-xerces=/opt/shibboleth-sp
this should find the xerces header files when xerces was installed properly.

Comment: Thank you so much! works fine!
I only get a warning `Warning - Xalan being configured out - XPath and XSLT will not be available`.. but works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`export CPPFLAGS=$HOME/opt/shibboleth-sp/include` and it should be able to find the headers.

I have an `export CFLAGS` set to my $PREFIX/include as well

Comment: Thnak you! but i get another error:
`configure: error: in /home/user/opt/xml-security-c-1.7.0:
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See config.log for more details` the config.log file: http://pastebin.com/Yn7LjRSZ

Comment: I didn't get this error.  I'd check with users@shibboleth.net they are pretty helpful and might recognize this one.  http://shibboleth.net/mailman/listinfo/users

Answer (score 0):

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/shibboleth-sp/lib/pkgconfig/
./configure --without-xalan --disable-static --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp
```